How to change the machine image "preemptible" flag in GCP?
I have a standard instance in GCP, configured and running for a couple of months, and I want to create SPOT instance clones from it.
My idea was to shutdown the instance, create a disk image, then create a VM instance from this image with the SPOT provisioning model.
The GCP Console lets me do this with Machine Images, but when the instance tries to start, I get this error:
Invalid value for field 'resource.scheduling.provisioningModel': 'SPOT'. preemptible=false and provisioning_model=SPOT is contradicting.

When I inspected the image, it indeed has Preemtibility: Off in Available policies but no way to edit that property. So apparently Machine images in GCP are not just disk images.
Is there a way to instantiate SPOT instance copies of my standard server at all?

It's a terminology issue: There are "Images" which are plain disk images, and there are "Machine images" which contain metadata.
Doing the process by creating an Image instead of Machine Image works.
